# KDE Konsole has Ctrl-C remapped to new tab

Tags: konsole

For a week or so, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> mapping does not send an interrupt, but opens a new tab with another profile. It might have happend around the time when there were updates for all KDE software.

I start with a single tab with the Solarized color scheme:

[image]

Then I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and get a new tab with a different profile:

[image]

However, if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, I get the interrupt:

[image]

In the settings, it seems all fine:

[image]

[image]

How can I get it back to have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> send an interrupt and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> copy text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I experienced the same frustrating behaviour.  While poking around I found that I had a profile mapped to a key combination that included <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

If you haven't already, you might want to check your profile short-cuts under `Settings -> Manage Profiles`.